# How to get a list of all valid ip address in a local network using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, networking, cordova

I'm writing a jQuery mobile/Cordova application for a mobile device, who can connect (say by WiFi) to a particular local network (LAN), who has a server that can provide some service that the app may use (some JSON data to populate a local storage).

In a given moment there can be several devices connected at the network. Say:

```
192.168.1.33
192.168.1.35
192.168.1.38
...
```

But the server not have a constant IP (depending on the wake up to the LAN) its IP can vary in a range.

The question is: how can get a list of the visibles IPs, to try in turn, get the service from the server?

Comment: It would be much simpler if you can set a static IP for the server.

Comment: you really want a list of all possible private IP addresses (192.168.0.0/16, 10.0.0.0/8, 172.16.0.0/20)? That would result in 17.9 million addresses, which would be quite a lot to check them turn by turn...

Comment: There are app app in the Play Store: "ES File Explorer" that do that instantly. The option Network -> LAN show all valid IPs at that moment.

Answer (score 0):

I once faced a similiar challange. What I did was:

1. Implementing a `/ping` serverwise that returns a json formatted response to the client.
2. So the "Client" just calls all IPs in own IP-Adress range (e.g. `192.168.178.1/ping` to `192.168.178.254/ping`) and in case there is a response:
3. You found your server.

IPs that are currently not taken by any client do no harm - so no need to find out which ones are valid. Code needed?