# Start a service in a LAN; the unknow server address case

Tags: c++, networking, network-interface

This questions are a new attempt to solve a previous question "How to get a list of all valid ip address in a local network using Javascript?" (see [How to get a list of all valid ip address in a local network using Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098575/) )

In order to avoid the need of test millions of addresses, I wonder if it would be possible following scenario (in this case, forget the JavaScriipt constraint of the initial post, and suppose a more general language, say C++ and a I/O library like Boost Asio):

a) A server "S" wakeup in a LAN to provide some service, say listening in port X, and get a random address (i.e A1 = 192.168.1.35).

b) A client "C", that need the service, wakeup in the same LAN, an get other random address (say A2 = 192.168.1.40).

"C" does not know the "S" address to get the service. So, two questions:

1.- Can "S" and "C" know for themselves its own addresses (A1 and A2)?

2.- Can "C" send a broadcast request to the LAN in the given port X?  Some as "Here P2, some one in X?"

Obviously, if "S" is listening in the given port, and can get the message, them can in turn broadcast its own direction; so if "C" is listening, can get the server's address.

Comment: Are you trying to reinvent [UPnP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Plug_and_Play), by any chance?

Comment: Uh. not at all, but trying to solve a concrete problem to populate an app dbase with real data.

Comment: May bi that some can be interested in read this: http://www.codeproject.com/Lounge.aspx?msg=4878760#xx4878760xx

Answer (score 0):

Related to my first question, after some digging, the answer is **Yes**.

See "[Winsock Programer's FAQ](http://tangentsoft.net/wskfaq/examples/ipaddr.html)".

If in Windows, as is my case for the server, there are a complete API named "**IP Helper**" http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366073%28VS.85%29.aspx that can serve as well.

Related to the second question, I will try the quick and dirty method exposed, and hope be back with some result.